# C++ Object Creation Time

Tags: c++, performance, object, a-star

So I'm building an A* search sort of thing and creating objects as below when needed within my algorithm. Thing is, they're taking .1 of a second each being created. My search takes 40 seconds, 39 seconds of which is object creation.

I really got no clue. Pretty new. Any help appreciated.

```
class Node{
private:
    int numAncestors;
    float gvalue;
    float hvalue;
    float fvalue;
    int adj;
    Node* parent;
public:
    inline Node(int vertex, int goal, vector< vector<double> > xy){

        adj = vertex - 1;
        float x1 = (float)xy[vertex-1][0];
        float y1 = (float)xy[vertex-1][1];
        float x2 = (float)xy[goal-1][0];
        float y2 = (float)xy[goal-1][1];
        hvalue = sqrtf((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
        //fvalue = hvalue + gvalue;
    }
    inline float getF(){
        return hvalue + gvalue;
    }

    inline void setG(float newG){
        gvalue = newG;
    }
    inline float getG(){
        return gvalue;
    }

    inline int getAncestors(){

        return numAncestors;
    }

    void setAncestors(int ancestors){

        numAncestors = ancestors;
    }
    void setParent(Node* n, vector< vector<double> > xy){

        parent = n;
        float x1 = (float)xy[n->getAdj()][0];
        float y1 = (float)xy[n->getAdj()][1];
        float x2 = (float)xy[adj][0];
        float y2 = (float)xy[adj][1];
        float x = sqrtf((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));

        setG(n->getG() + x);
        setAncestors(n->getAncestors()+1);
     }

    inline Node* getParent(){

        return parent;
    }

    inline int getAdj(){

        return adj;
    }
};
```

This takes .1 seconds:

```
clock_t nodetest = clock();    
Node* s = new Node(g,e,xy);
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - nodetest)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

This takes 0.0 seconds:

```
clock_t thisLoop = clock();
float x1 = (float)xy[x-1][0];
float y1 = (float)xy[x-1][1];
float x2 = (float)xy[current->getAdj()][0];
float y2 = (float)xy[current->getAdj()][1];
float x = sqrtf((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - thisLoop)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

I would have thought maybe it was what the object was up to or whatever, but it seems from that the entirety of the time spent is just in object creation.

Comment: Have you enabled compiler optimisations? `xy` should probably be passed to the `Node` constructor by (const) reference. A 2D vector is quite inefficient, consider using a 1D vector with lookup functions to achieve the same result, it seems the inner vector always has 2 elements? If so `std::array<double, 2>` would also fix the inefficiency of a 2D vector. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited above. I don't know if that's minimal reproducible but that Node* s is created just as a line on its own in main, no function around it or anything. Seems to me it's entirely just in creating the object I'm losing .1 seconds. Which seems so wrong to me given everything else my program is doing in so little time extra.

Comment: @Sean It is fairly minimal, but it's not reproducible since it lacks the definitions of `g`, `e`, and `xy`. The last of these is of the most interest seeing how we have no idea how big it is. Have you timed something like `vector< vector<double> > test{xy};` (simply making a copy of `xy`)?

Comment: The xy was huge, yes. Thanks for the help lads. I do really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `Node` constructor, you are passing `xy` *by value*, meaning a copy is made of the entire array.  You should pass it by *const reference*:

```
Node(int vertex, int goal, const vector<vector<double>> &xy)
```

This should also be done for `setParent`.

Other notes:

The `Node` constructor does not initialize all of its members.  In particular, `parent` will have a garbage value in it, which can lead to strange bugs later.

The `Node` constructor and `setParent` share a bunch of code that does some work.  This should be placed in a (private) member function that can be called to avoid the code duplication.

The various `get` functions can be `const`, e.g. `float getF() const;`.

You don't need the `inline` keyword, since any function defined within the class definition is implicitly inline.

Comment: Friend I could kiss you haha. Wow thank you so very much.